# Hi, I am getting 404 not found in postman while running POST API

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0

For referenece, I have attached the code  for Customer Modal, Customer controller (Post request) and postman response,

Customer Controller: (post Req)

```
     [HttpPost]
     public async Task<ActionResult<Customer>> PostCustomer(Customer customer)
     {
          if (_context.Customers == null)
          {
              return Problem("Entity set 'SalesContext.Customers'  is null.");
          }

          _context.Customers.Add(customer);
          await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

          return CreatedAtAction("GetCustomer", new { id = customer.CustomerID }, customer);
    }
```

Customer model:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Postman :

Post request URL: https://localhost:44458/api/Customer_CRUD

Req. Body:

```
{
    "Name":"abc",
    "Address":"abc"
}
```

Response : 404 not found

404 not found coming in post request, should  come 201

Response code should be 200 in place of 404, not able to identify mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the route attributes to change the default URL for your controller actions:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/Customer_CRUD")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Customer>> PostCustomer(Customer customer)
{
    // your code
}
```

If you do not use route annotations in your controller, ASP.NET Core uses a default routing convention. The URL pattern for the default routing convention is `{controller}/{action}/{id?}`.

Assuming the controller class name is `CustomerController` and the action method name is `PostCustomer`, you would make a POST request to the following URL:

```
https://localhost:44458/Customer/PostCustomer
```